# Non deterministic behavior with synchronizedList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am trying to understand the concept of `Collections.synchronizedList()` but the below code does not work properly.According to my understanding, `synchronizedList` will synchronise all methods of ArrayList and putting it inside `synchronised` block will prevent other thread from accessing/modification of object on which lock is acquired.Below is my code.

```
 public class SynchronisedList {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    static ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=0;i<50000;i++)
            list.add("String"+i);


        final List<String> list1=Collections.synchronizedList(list); 

        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Thread 1 started");

                synchronized (list1) 
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<50000;i++)
                    {

                        System.out.println(list1.get(i));
                        //System.out.println(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread 2 started");
                list1.clear();
        }
        });


        thread.start();

        thread1.start();

    }

}
```

My expected output is Thread 1 will iterate will through arraylist `list1` and then Thread 2 will clear it.but I am getting error as,

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 432, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.get(Collections.java:1816)
    at com.common.List.SynchronisedList$1.run(SynchronisedList.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Am I doing any wrong here?Please help.

Comment: Thread2 works on the unsynchronized `list`, the result you get is to be expected! Creating a synchronized `list1` (backed by `list`) doesn't automagically make `list` thead safe.

Comment: @ammoQ I have replaced `list` with `list1` but still getting same error.

Comment: `thread.start(); thread1.start();` doesn't mean that `thread1` can't be faster to lock `list1` than `thread`, just by accident.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve your exepcted output, both iteration and clearing should be in a`synchronized` block, and you should synchronized on the original list, list1 is redundant